# .Net Maui - ShellContent navigation issue

Tags: maui, maui-windows, .net-maui.shell

I am trying to navigate to page "TestView" which is in folder "Views" of my VisualStudio solution.
Here the compile Error.

Error XFC0000 Cannot resolve type ":TestView"

AppShell.xaml file

```
<FlyoutItem Title="test" FlyoutIcon="List">

        <ShellContent
        Title="Test Page"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:TestView}"
        Route="TestView" />
    </FlyoutItem>
```

Need Help to solve the Compile Error

Here the link to my GitHub project [MPC-Calculator Maui Branch](https://github.com/JeanMarcFlamand/MPC-MassPropertiesCalculator/tree/MAUI/MPC-MassPropertiesCalculator-MAUIapp)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your namespace in your shell from:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MPC_MassPropertiesCalculator_MAUIapp"
```

To this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MPC_MassPropertiesCalculator_MAUIapp.Views"
```

Basically if you wanna refer a View in your XAML you need to have its exact namespace and then the name of your View.

Comment: Thanks problem solve using your proposal.

Comment: Happy to help, If you are looking for extended MAUI controls for Android and iOS you can check my lib out : https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls

Comment: final fix  is xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MPC_MassPropertiesCalculator_MAUIapp",
    xmlns:page="clr-namespace:MPC_MassPropertiesCalculator_MAUIapp.Views" ..... ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:TestView}" .....

Comment: OMG this helped me a lot.. new to maui and spend 2-3hrs before I bumped on this. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you can update the name of the local namespace or define a new one.

For example, add this to the `Shell`

`xmlns:mynamespace="clr-namespace:MPC_MassPropertiesCalculator_MAUIapp.Views"` and then you can use it with

```
<FlyoutItem Title="test" FlyoutIcon="List">
        <ShellContent
        Title="Test Page"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate mynamespace:TestView}"
        Route="TestView" />
</FlyoutItem>
```